# ListAdapter getView is called only once for a List of 64, noting is shown at all

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

**Update:** The root cause is not in this code. 
Apparently it is related to an image view that I placed in the background of the list view. It seems that the list was located at the bottom of the screen just under the background image. 
Strange, though, the same layout did work nicely in the neighbour tab which shows a list view too.

I've got a list adapter that is supposed to display 64 data items. `getCount` does return 64 as far as the Log.d statements show. But `getView` is called only one time with the index `i` of 0. 
The data that is logged at the end of getView looks nice so far.

Sorry for that bunch of code but I don't know which part is where the problem is. I am happy to share even more if you think that the error could be in the list fragment itself or whatever you suggest to look at.

```
public class SpieleAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm");

    public SpieleAdapter (Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("SpieleAdapter", "Anzahl spiele: " + WorldCupManager.getGameList().size());
        return WorldCupManager.getGameList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return WorldCupManager.getGameList().get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return (long) i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        Log.d("SpieleAdapter", "Liefere View Nr. " + i);

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zelle_spiel, viewGroup, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.gruppeView     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gruppeText);
            viewHolder.heimView       = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heimText);
            viewHolder.gastView       = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gastText);
            viewHolder.heimToreView   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heimToreText);
            viewHolder.gastToreView   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gastToreText);
            viewHolder.zeitOrtView    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zeitOrtText);
            viewHolder.zusatzView     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zusatzText);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        Spiel spiel = (Spiel) WorldCupManager.getGameList().get(i);
        Gruppe gruppe = spiel.gruppe;




        viewHolder.gruppeView.setText(gruppe.name);
        Team heim = spiel.heim;
        viewHolder.heimView.setText (heim == null ? spiel.platzhalterHeim : heim.name);
        Team gast = spiel.gast;
        viewHolder.heimView.setText (gast == null ? spiel.platzhalterGast : gast.name);

        viewHolder.heimView.setText(spiel.heim.name);
        viewHolder.gastView.setText(spiel.gast.name);
        viewHolder.heimToreView.setText("" + spiel.toreHeim);
        viewHolder.gastToreView.setText("" + spiel.toreGast);
        viewHolder.zusatzView.setText(spiel.zusatz);

        viewHolder.zeitOrtView.setText(df.format(spiel.anstoss) + " in " + spiel.ort.name);

        Log.d("SpieleAdapter", "Daten: " + viewHolder.gruppeView.getText () + " " + viewHolder.heimView.getText () + " " + viewHolder.gastView.getText () + " " + viewHolder.zeitOrtView.getText () + " " + viewHolder.gruppeView.getText () + " " );

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView gruppeView;
        public TextView heimView;
        public TextView gastView;
        public TextView heimToreView;
        public TextView gastToreView;
        public TextView zeitOrtView;
        public TextView zusatzView;
    }
}
```

and the related xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:padding="4dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gruppeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="14dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Gruppe A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heimText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gruppeText"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Heim Team"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heimToreText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gruppeText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/heimText"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gastText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/heimText"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Gast Team"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gastToreText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/heimText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/gastText"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zeitOrtText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gastText"
        android:layout_height="14dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Datum, Uhrzeit und Ort"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zusatzText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gastText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/zeitOrtText"
        android:layout_height="14dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dip"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am currently using Android Studio on a Mac, if that makes a difference.

Edit in response to Arash's question: 
This is the fragment class where the adapter is set.

```
public class SpieleFragment  extends ListFragment {

    private SpieleAdapter spieleAdapter = null;

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent

            //Check UI Thread
            boolean onUiThread = (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper());
            if (onUiThread) {
                Log.d("SpieleFragment", "runs on UI Thread");
            } else {
                Log.d("SpieleFragment", "does not run un UI Thread");
            }

            if (spieleAdapter != null) {
                spieleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            Log.d("SpieleFragment", "Got message data changed");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spiele, container, false);

        spieleAdapter = new SpieleAdapter(this.getActivity());
        setListAdapter(spieleAdapter);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(WMApp.getContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(WorldCupManager.UPDATE_EVENT));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
        // This is somewhat like [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:name:object:]
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(WMApp.getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the part of setting your adapter or part of WorldCupManager.getGameList()?

Comment: @Arash, I do that in a minute. WorldCupManager.getGameList() is dead boring. I retruns an ArrayList. Apparently the correct data arrives in the adapter's methods.

Comment: just remove super() method in constuctor. then check it.

Comment: change return WorldCupManager.getGameList().get(i); to return i;

Comment: @kyogs, are you referring to `getItem()`? Why should I do that, despite that `i` is an `int` ant not an object?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used Different class object for ref so refer below code

```
ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
       if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zelle_spiel, viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            .....
            .....
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

       ......
       ......
```

Comment: I'm agree with this answer, i think else part needed

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue. 1. Even if it was then getView should be called a couple of times anyway. 2. It would work nicely with 2 different objects as long as they are used properly. 3. The problem was there even before I adopted the view-holder pattern.

Comment: And by the way it is the very same objects, theres just two references to it.

Comment: @HermannKlecker did you have error in your code? try comment `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance...` and run again

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, I get no build error nor related warnings. There is not error dumped on the logcat. Why should I comment out the broadcast manager? It is of importance for my business logic when updated data arrives. It works nicely in another list view of the same project. What is wrong with that, please advise.

Comment: @HermannKlecker i told that just for test, See Arash's answer, he right,

Comment: See my response to Arash's answer. Yes, he is rigt. I did post the wrong class in my question. Apologies. Please see the related class now.

Comment: @HermannKlecker did you tried remove `super();` in Adapter class constructor? your code is OK, as you get right number in `getCount`, `getView` must be run correctly. please remove that and test again

Comment: I always thought calling a superclass' method, including constructors, is good practice, not only in Java. However I tried that but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know there is a misunderstanding or not but you've posted the `SpieleAdapter` but in your `ListFragment` you've initialized `GruppenAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is a misunderstanding. I posted the fragment of another similar but well working list. I'll fix that in my question.

Comment: @HermannKlecker : your edited codes seems fine , i think it's about your returning of WorldCupManager.getGameList().size() timing.maybe you've initialized your adapter before you've filled your list compeletely.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the adapter was initialized before the list was filled completely. Most likely at least. That is what happens to the adapter of my first list - the one that works fine. The data displayed is loaded asynchronously. Once updated sorted, formatted etc. a broadcast message is sent which is received by each fragment that displays data within a tab view. Then `notifyDataIsChanged()` is called on each of the list adapters. As I said, this principle works fine already on the list in my first tab.